# How can I create data structure in java having records from 3 tables?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, data-structures, oracle11g

How can I create data structure in java having records from 3 tables?

### Query/ Total number of records.

```
select * from TRANSACTION where workitemid = '104854'; (1 Record)
select * from WHT where workitemid = '104854'; (1 Record)
select * from FX where workitemid = '104854'; (2 Record)
```

### Data structure in JAVA.

```
PSRResponseReportDTO{
    String workitemid;

    public PSRResponseReportDTO() {
        this.fxDetail = new HashSet<PSRResponseReportDTO>();        
        this.whtDetails = new HashSet<PSRResponseReportDTO>();
        this.invoiceDetails = new HashSet<PSRResponseReportDTO>();
    }
}
```

### Query

```
select ptw.workitemid
       , pttd.workitemid   as PAY_TXN_TAX_DETAILS_WORK_ID 
       , ptsi.workitemid   as pay_txn_supp_inf_work_id
from TRANSACTION ptw
     , WHT pttd
     , FX ptsi
where ptw.workitemid = pttd.workitemid (+)
AND ptw.workitemid =  ptsi.workitemid (+)
AND ptw.workitemid = '104854'
order by ptw.workitemid;
```

The table does not have a primary key, only a foreign key. Fallows an example of the obtained data. The question is how to identify that for for Fx there are two rows and for WHT there is one row?

Result from query:

```
|  PTW   |   WHT   |   FX   | PTW.COLUMN1 | FX_COLUMN1 | WHT_COLUMN 1 |
+--------+---------+--------+-------------+------------+--------------+
| 104854 |  104854 | 104854 |      1      |     2      |      3       |
| 104854 |  104854 | 104854 |      1      |     2      |      3       |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `count()` a to get number of `WHT` and `FX` placed in a subquery.

```
select t1.workitemid, count(1) as ptwNumRows
    , (select count(1) ct from WHT t2 where t2.workitemid = t1.workitemid) as pttdNumRows
    , (select count(1) ct from FX t3 where t3.workitemid = t1.workitemid)   as ptsiNumRows
from TRANSACTION t1
where t1.workitemid = '104854'
order by t1.workitemid;
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=PqFvfCQ7r9)